# How to fix show function of doubly link-list?

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have created a Doubly Linked List program where i have  two function, 
inserthead(int x) and display();
But when i run the program the display function shows the list in reverse order.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct doublelinklist {
    int data;
    doublelinklist* pre;
    doublelinklist* next;
};

struct doublelinklist* head = NULL;
struct doublelinklist* tail = NULL;

inserthead(int x)
{
    doublelinklist* newnode = new doublelinklist;

    newnode->data = x;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->pre = NULL;

    if (head != NULL) {

        newnode->next = head;
        head->pre = newnode;
        head = newnode;
    }
    else {
        head = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
    }
}

display()
{
    doublelinklist* position = head;

    cout << "\nDOUBLE LINK LIST: ";
    while (position != NULL) {
        cout << position->data << " ";
        position = position->next;
    }
    cout << "" << endl;
}
main()
{

    inserthead(10);
    inserthead(20);
    inserthead(30);
    inserthead(40);

    display();
}
```

I expect the output of DOUBLE LINK LIST: 10 20 30 40 but the actual output is 40 30 20 10

Comment: Given the way you have named your function `inserthead` the output is correct. `40` has been inserted at the head of the list, so it prints first. So maybe you're just confused about your requirements and everything is OK. If not then you really need to rename that function so no-one else is confused.

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching your `newnode` to the front of the list instead of to the rear.  Then you call the newly inserted node at the rear of the list `head`.

```
newnode->next = head;
head->pre = newnode;
head = newnode;
```

Instead of attaching the `newnode` to the `head`, attach it to the `tail`.

```
tail -> next = newnode;
newnode -> pre = tail;
tail = newnode;
```

These changes should fix your problem.

**Edit**: Your function name should be `insertTail` if you want to build the list front to back.  The current name `inserthead` sounds like you want to always insert a new node at the `head` node where it will remain.

Comment: @john You’re correct.  I just read your comment concerning the method name.  The current output might be correct if the problem asked for a list in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Doubly Linked List works perfectly. As you always insert at the head, your list will be:

Step 1: `10  // inserthead(10);`

Step 2: `20 10 //inserthead(20);`

Step 3: `30 20 10 // inserthead(30);`

Step 4: `40 30 20 10 // inserthead(40);`

Therefore, the display will be 40, 30, 20, 10.